# Redirection for a specific page of a specific domain in multi-domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My website is configured to work on different domains for different languages, therefore I have one htaccess to manage everything.

I would like to redirect from **mydomain.de/page1** to **mydomain.de/page2** but if to keep **mydomain.com/page1** and **mydomain.fr/page1**, etc as it is (no redirection for other domains with the same path name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found it :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.mydomain.de/page2 [R=301,L]
```

[Test here](https://htaccess.mwl.be?share=fb9071b8-069c-59cf-9c59-096ad815edb9)